# Integration with AD B2C: Trigger Owin challenges by policy name

Tags: xconnect, azure, owin, adb2c

We're using Sitecore.NET 9.1.0.

We're trying to trigger register, login and forgot password flows from Sitecore that will be used by end users of our website.

After a successful login we want to identify/create a Sitecore contact and update it's facets with the user details (for this we've create a custom processor added on `owin.cookieAuthentication.signedIn` pipeline)

I've configured federated authentication for Sitecore accounts but it seems I'm missing something, as the virtual user is not created at all in Sitecore after a successful login.

I've managed to trigger AD B2C flows from Sitecore using Owin challenges, the **AspNet.Cookie** is successfully created afte a register/login, however `owin.cookieAuthentication.signedIn` custom processor is not triggered.

My configurations are the following:

```
<pipelines>
  <owin.identityProviders>
    <processor type="Feature.ADB2C.Pipeline.Processors.IdentityProviderProcessor, Feature.ADB2C" resolve="true" />
  </owin.identityProviders>
  <owin.cookieAuthentication.signedIn>
    <processor type="Feature.Accounts.Pipelines.TrackSignedIn, Feature.Accounts" resolve="true" />
  </owin.cookieAuthentication.signedIn>
</pipelines>
<services>
  <register serviceType="Sitecore.Abstractions.BaseAuthenticationManager, Sitecore.Kernel"
            implementationType="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Security.AuthenticationManager, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication"
            lifetime="Singleton" />
  <register serviceType="Sitecore.Abstractions.BaseTicketManager, Sitecore.Kernel"
            implementationType="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Security.TicketManager, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication"
            lifetime="Singleton" />
  <register serviceType="Sitecore.Abstractions.BasePreviewManager, Sitecore.Kernel"
            implementationType="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Publishing.PreviewManager, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication"
            lifetime="Singleton" />
</services>
<federatedAuthentication type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Configuration.FederatedAuthenticationConfiguration, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
  <identityProviders hint="list:AddIdentityProvider">
    <identityProvider id="xp0.azureAD" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Configuration.DefaultIdentityProvider, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
      <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
      <param desc="domainManager" type="Sitecore.Abstractions.BaseDomainManager" resolve="true" />
      <caption>Go To Azure B2C</caption>
      <domain>custom</domain>
      <icon>/sitecore/shell/themes/standard/Images/24x24/msazure.png</icon>
      </identityProvider>
  </identityProviders>
  <propertyInitializer type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.PropertyInitializer, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
    <!--List of property mappings
            Note that all mappings from the list will be applied to each providers-->
    <maps hint="list">
      <!--The mapping sets the Email property of the user profile from emailaddress claim-->
      <map name="email" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultClaimToPropertyMapper, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" resolve="true">
        <data hint="raw:AddData">
          <!--claim name-->
          <source name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress" />
          <!--property name-->
          <target name="Email" />
        </data>
      </map>          
      <map name="Object Id" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultClaimToPropertyMapper, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" resolve="true">
        <data hint="raw:AddData">
          <source name="objectId" />
          <target name="Name" />
        </data>
      </map>
    </maps>
  </propertyInitializer>
  <identityProvidersPerSites>
    <mapEntry name="Custom" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Collections.IdentityProvidersPerSitesMapEntry, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
      <sites hint="list">
        <site>MySite</site>
        <site>Portal</site>
      </sites>          
      <identityProviders hint="list:AddIdentityProvider">
        <identityProvider ref="federatedAuthentication/identityProviders/identityProvider[@id='xp0.azureAD']" />
      </identityProviders>
      <externalUserBuilder type="Foundation.ADB2C.Services.ExternalUserBuilder,Foundation.ADB2C">
        <param desc="isPersistentUser">false</param>
      </externalUserBuilder>       
    </mapEntry>
  </identityProvidersPerSites>
</federatedAuthentication>
```

IdentityProviderProcessor looks like this:

```
 protected override string IdentityProviderName => "xp0.azureAD";

    protected override void ProcessCore(IdentityProvidersArgs args)
    {
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, nameof(args));

        var identityProvider = this.GetIdentityProvider();           

        args.App.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        args.App.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
        args.App.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(this.CreateOptionsFromPolicy(identityProvider, "B2C_1_login"));
        args.App.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(this.CreateOptionsFromPolicy(identityProvider, "B2C_1_registration"));
    }

    private OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions CreateOptionsFromPolicy(IdentityProvider identityProvider, string policy = "B2C_1_registration")
    {
        var authenticationType = this.GetAuthenticationType();
        var options = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            MetadataAddress = string.Format(WellKnownMetadata, Tenant, policy),
            AuthenticationType = policy,
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive,
            ClientId = ClientId,
            RedirectUri = RedirectUri,
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = PostLogoutRedirectUri,
            Scope = "openid",
            ResponseType = "id_token",
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
            {
                AuthenticationFailed = this.AuthenticationFailed,
                RedirectToIdentityProvider = notification =>
                {
                    return Task.FromResult(notification.ProtocolMessage.UiLocales = string.Empty);
                },
                SecurityTokenValidated = notification =>
                {
                    notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("idp", "xp0.azureAD"));

                    // transform all claims
                    ClaimsIdentity identity = notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;
                    notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.ApplyClaimsTransformations(new TransformationContext(this.FederatedAuthenticationConfiguration, identityProvider));

                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                },
            },

            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                NameClaimType = "emails",
            },
        };
        return options;
    }
```

And this is how I trigger a policy from Account Controller:

```
  [Route("signin")]
    [HttpGet]
    public void SignIn()
    {
        var redirectUrl = "/account";
        if (!this.Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            this.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = redirectUrl }, "B2C_1_login");
            return;
        }

        this.Response.Redirect("/");
    }
```

Could anyone advise please what I'm missing? Should I create manually a virtual user (we don't want to persist the users), I would have expected this is handled by Sitecore (I might be wrong)?

Thanks